# Continuous gradient through multiple elements

Tags: html, css, navigation, gradient

I'm trying to create a circle/pie nav that consists of four menu items. The overall menu should have a gradient with four main colors. The menu items need to be independent as they have hover effects.

I would like the gradient to display seamlessly over all the elements.

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Here is a snippet to show you what I've done so far. As you can see, the gradient is applied to each element vs appearing uniform.

Also, when trying to use a linear or radial gradient, I haven't been able to create this quadrent-type gradient where each section is the primary color and then fades into the next section.

Any help is appreciated.

```css
ul {
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: gray;
}

ul a {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(
    49deg,
    #6a3fc5 0%,
    #f44336 25%,
    #009688 50%,
    #ffc107 100%
  );
}
ul a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

ul a:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
}
ul a:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}
ul a:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
}
ul a:nth-child(4):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}

ul a:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul a:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0em;
  left: 10em;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul a:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10em;a
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul a:nth-child(4) {
  top: 10em;
  left: 10em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <a href="/"><li class="item">Targeting</li></a>
   <a href="/"><li class="item">Optimization</li></a>
   <a href="/"><li class="item">Enablement</li></a>
   <a href="/"><li class="item">Measurement</li></a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Try conic-gradient on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: conic-gradient(#81408e, #c84955, #f05435, #b58835, #7fbd37, #3baf75, #00a4b2, #3770a2, #81408e);
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: blur(15px);
}

.circle-container {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
   <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best way is probably to use the image directly. @_@

Comment: This works fine, but a bit of explanation, including your comment, in the actual answer would make this more valuable to readers.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think, instead of using background on "ul a" you should use the gradient only on the "ul" like below:

```css
ul {
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: gray;
}

ul a {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  
}

ul {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(
    49deg,
    #6a3fc5 0%,
    #f44336 25%,
    #009688 50%,
    #ffc107 100%
  );
}
ul a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

ul a:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
}
ul a:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}
ul a:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
}
ul a:nth-child(4):hover {
  background: #999;
  z-index: 19;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}

ul a:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul a:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0em;
  left: 10em;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul a:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10em;a
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul a:nth-child(4) {
  top: 10em;
  left: 10em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <a href="/"><li class="item">Targeting</li></a>
   <a href="/"><li class="item">Optimization</li></a>
   <a href="/"><li class="item">Enablement</li></a>
   <a href="/"><li class="item">Measurement</li></a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: This gives a sort of stripey gradient, not like in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conic gradient or the image itself as discussed in the comments or you can use a blur on an element that contains all of the elements you want to form the gradient and have a parent div that uses `overflow-hidden` on the blurred element with a high border radius. Then place that under your interactive hover layer which can be what you already have but with a transparent background to begin with so the gradient shows through..

I would recommend making the container you are going to blur be a bit larger than the container that will hide the overflow to prevent white feathering at the outer edges of the circle.

I'd also recommend using an SVG cross positioned absolutely over the elements instead of borders if you want to get closer to your original design.

In this example I'm using grid for placement to force some elements on top of one another without absolute positioning but absolute positioning the elements would work just as well.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
}

.cross {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  pointer-events: none
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.item, .item:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0em;
  left: 10em;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10em;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  top: 10em;
  left: 10em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}

.item span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(2) span {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item:nth-child(3) span {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item:nth-child(1) span {
  position: relative;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: 1.5em
}

.item:nth-child(4) span {
  position: relative;
  top: -.75em;
  right: .75em
}

.item:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: #999;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
}

.item:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: #999;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}

.item:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: #999;
  transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
}

.item:nth-child(4):hover {
  background: #999;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}

.gradient-concealer {
  height: 20em;
  width: 20em;
  border-radius: 99999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2
}

.gradient {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  background: #fff;
  filter: blur(30px);
  height: 24em;
  width: 24em;
  position: relative;
  top: -2em;
  left: -2em
}

.purple {
  background-color: #ca61df;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(202, 97, 223, 1) 11%, rgba(143, 97, 223, 1) 47%);
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff5932;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #16c5d3;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(25, 205, 219, 1) 18%, rgba(29, 166, 177, 1) 47%);
}

.green {
  background-color: #90d33c;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="/" class="item">
      <span>targeting</span>
    </a>
    <a href="/" class="item">
      <span>optimization</span>
    </a>
    <a href="/" class="item">
      <span>enablement</span>
    </a>
    <a href="/" class="item">
      <span>measurement</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="cross">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="#fff">
        <line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="19" y1="5" x2="5" y2="19" />
        <line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="5" y1="5" x2="19" y2="19" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="gradient-concealer">
    <div class="gradient">
      <div class="purple"></div>
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```